# What's the name of an episode of The Twilight Zone where all war must be stopped to appease aliens?

Tags: story-identification, tv, the-twilight-zone

I just recalled (who knows why) an episode of *The Twilight Zone*. The world seemed to be at war, and the aliens arrived making an ultimatum to the United Nations to stop all the confrontations or there will be total obliteration. The members of the United Nations, in the spite of this, signed a peace threat, and it was showed to the aliens (who looked like Data from *Star Trek: The Next Generation*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of "A Small Talent For War," from season 1, episode 15 of the 1986 revival of *The Twilight Zone*.

The story proceeds essentially as you describe

> When an alien visitor tells delegates at the United Nations that humanity will be exterminated because it has "a small talent for war," the countries of the world struggle to forge a disarmament treaty before the visitor's deadline

... although there is a twist ending.  I'm not sure if I would say that the alien representative played by [John Glover](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001278/) looks like Data, but he is very pasty.

Comment: Indeed, the ambassador does not looks like Data, I mixed them, but somehow it resembles him (for me!). Thanks for the episode, the end was as I remembered, so I didn't want to write in the question. =)

Comment: @riccs_0x: All's well in the end, but in the future, we want people to provide all of the details. You can always put spoilers under a spoiler tag so that a casual viewer won't encounter them.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, Thanks, I will.